# Application configuration file

Tags: clojure

I am wondering what approach/library is considered a good practise in clojure app development for configuration files?
I would like to keep some settings e.g. database connection, credentials to access external web services etc, in the external configuration file.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clojure Cookbook has a section exactly on that: https://github.com/clojure-cookbook/clojure-cookbook/blob/master/04_local-io/4-15_edn-config.asciidoc.

Answer (score 2):

EDN is a good solution. However, you might also like the clojure environ library. This giv3es quite a nice abstraction for using environment variables, java property files, end etc.